# difference between AKFrequencyTracker and AKMicrophoneTracker in AudioKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audiokit

I found that there are `AKFrequencyTracker` and `AKMicrophoneTracker` in the lib. And both provides frequency as param.

The questions are:

1. What the difference between `AKFrequencyTracker` and
   `AKMicrophoneTracker`?
2. What class is better to use for a real-time microphone singing detection?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

AKMicrophoneTracker is a standalone class that just reads from the microphone and nothing more whereas the AKFrequencyTracker is a node that can be inserted at any point in your signal chain. They both use the same frequency detection algorithm, its just that the AKMicrophoneTracker is easier to use for the common case where all you need is pitch detection and nothing else AudioKit provides.

Comment: Hi Aurelius. Thank you for help. That what I was expected. One more question. I found AKMicrophoneTrackerEngine in the lib. Is the class obsolete? If No would you please add more details regarding how to use it. As I didn't find any info in AudioKit help section. Thank you